# Excel Bar chart show Y Axes C#

Tags: c#, excel, charts, bar-chart

I created a bar chart in asp.Net4.0 using MS Chart. i.e.

[image]

Same chart I want to show in Excel so I tried to create the same chart using C# but i am not able to show Y axes category. Please suggest me how I can do this.
Suppose data is:

Category  Value
Cate1     -8
Cate2      4
Cate3      2
Cate4     -8
Cate5      0

in Excel showing:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I done this myself with the help of Excel settings :)

```
Axis yAxes = (Axis)xlChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
yAxes.MajorTickMark = XlTickMark.xlTickMarkCross;
yAxes.TickLabelPosition = XlTickLabelPosition.xlTickLabelPositionLow;
```

Hope so it will help to someone.

Thanks,